# wkhtmltopdf in heroku: memory issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

I've a Rails 4.2.3 / Ruby 2.2.2 app running in a free dyno in Heroku.

I'm using the [wkhtmltopdf-buildpack](https://github.com/dscout/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack) but Heroku logs show me Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) every time that I try to generate a PDF file. This is an example:

```
2015-07-31T02:06:52.005696+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/orders/1.pdf" for 200.149.16.70 at 2015-07-31 02:06:52 +0000
2015-07-31T02:06:52.162915+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered clients/_client.html.erb (85.3ms)
2015-07-31T02:06:52.015043+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by OrdersController#show as PDF
2015-07-31T02:06:52.015049+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2015-07-31T02:06:52.071357+00:00 app[web.1]: ***************WICKED***************
2015-07-31T02:06:52.309300+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered orders/_order_products.html.erb (145.6ms)
2015-07-31T02:06:52.339531+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered orders/show.html.erb (267.2ms)
2015-07-31T02:06:52.339015+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered orders/_order.html.erb (262.6ms)
2015-07-31T02:07:12.162183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=662M(129.4%)
2015-07-31T02:07:12.162183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2015-07-31T02:07:22.005012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/orders/1.pdf" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=50f6840e-1907-4730-ab0d-1a6f415eb3db fwd="200.*.*.*" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

I had tried before wkhtmltopdf-heroku gem but I got the same memory problem.
I'm not sure about how to debug this issue, but could you help? Is adding dynos an option in this case?

Comment: How large is your HTML document which you are trying to convert ? Can you pick a use case where document size is very small and try it out ? I am successfully using  `wkhtmltopdf-heroku` gem to generate single page PDF document on `Heroku`.

Comment: It is small document, I just solve my problem using gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

Comment: oh right I am using `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem sorry.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: I solved the problem using the gem wkhtmltopdf-binary. I also tried the gem wkhtmltopdf-heroku, but this didn't work.

Comment: My problem was that I included the bootstrap stylesheet in my manifest file and it appeared to have been to much for the poor free dyno to handle.